Sheet button ui formatting
We are doing sheet and we encode the data. I would like to have a button that will format the range of the cell for
eg: when I click the button the sheet will create its own borders, colors, filters and etc.
Sample Sheet

I only have this code to start with:
function formatSheet(){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  let headers = sheet.getRange('A1:G1');
  let table = sheet.getDataRange();

  headers.setFontWeight('bold');
  headers.setFontColor('white');
  headers.setBackground('#52489C');

  table.setFontFamily('Roboto');
  table.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  table.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#52489C', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
}  

I want to make have buttons that will auto format the sheets for me and button to remove all of the formatting.

A button means a lot of maintenance (copying the button to each sheet). Have you thought of a using a custom menu - it will work with any sheet, any time. So far as removing the formatting, look at clearFormats().

The post doesn't include specific problems that are unique to programming. Please be specific about one of the missing formatting settings and what you have tried to add to that setting.  By the way, the image shows a "table"; now, using Google Apps Scripts, it's impossible to convert a range into a "table".

By using Drawing or using getUi()
To create a custom button theres 2 ways on how to create.
First one is by using Drawing:

After you draw the shape and putting a text just click assign script.

Second is using SpreadsheetApp.getUi():
let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu').addItem('Format Headers', 'formatSheet').addToUi();

See image below:

Reference:

Class Ui


Add a blank tab and give it a name like Template. Format Template manually, and duplicate it when creating additional tabs, instead of creating new tabs from scratch. See Sheet.copyTo().
To remove formatting, use Sheet.clearFormats().
To re-apply formatting, copy original formats from Template. See Range.copyFormatToRange().
